# Formula for a bent line

Tags: graphing-functions

This may be simple, but I don't know the answer.

I have the following data: (0,0) (1,12) (2,24) (3,30) (4,36) (5,42) (6,48) (7,54) and so on, the y coordinate increasing by 6 for values above 2 and by 12 for X values of 0, 1 and 2.

Is there a simple equation for that line? What should I be googling?

Comment: The origin of the data may provide some help.  Is it from an experiment or financial data or what ?

Comment: Eh, it's actually from a computer science past exam paper. Honestly this is a curiousity thing not anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to express it as a function, then you do so by defining the function *piecewise*:

$y = f(x) = \left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
12x & x \lt 12 \\
6x + 12 & x \ge 12
\end{array}
\right.$

Alternatively, you can write it using something like the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), but that's just doing exactly the same thing but hiding the piecewise nature of your function.

Comment: Thank you. Never seen that notation before and was just at a loss what to search for.